# Word VBA code to insert documents with diffrent paper sizes?

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Hello,**

How can I use the Word VBA code to insert another document including its paper size? I mean if I insert 5 documents with different paper sizes then it needs to be in the main document with these different paper sizes.

***For example:***

- Document(1) - A4
- Document(2) - Letter
- Document(3) - A3

Then in the main document there will be pages with different paper settings like A4, Letter and A3.

How do I code that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need to keep each part of the document in separate section. Each section will have then its own page size.
Did you try any code on your own?

Comment: I did try on my own and figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer myself and here is the code for it,

```
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
```

You have to use th above code to break the page and then,

```
Selection.PageSetup.PageHeight = <size>
Selection.PageSetup.PageWidth = <size>
```

The cursor in the document needs to on the specific page for the above code to work.

To make the page setup apply to the specific part of the document you have to use the `Selection` as shown above.